# How to format a csv file using json data?

Tags: json, excel, csv, converters

I have a json file that I need to convert to a csv file, but I am a little wary of trusting a json-to-csv converter site as the outputted data seems to be incorrect... so I was hoping to get some help here!

I have the following json file structure:

```
{
    "GroupName": "GrpName13",
    "Number": 3,
    "Notes": "Test Group ",
    "Units": [
    {
        "UnitNumber": "TestUnit13",
        "DataSource": "Factory",
        "ContractNumber": "TestContract13",
        "CarNumber": "2",
        "ControllerTypeMessageId" : 4,
        "NumberOfLandings": 4,
        "CreatedBy": "user1",
        "CommissionModeMessageId": 2,
        "Details": [
        {
            "DetailName": "TestFloor13",
            "DetailNumber": "5"
        }
        ],
        "UnitDevices": [
        {
            "DeviceTypeMessageId": 1,
            "CreatedBy": "user1"
        }                               
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

The issue I think Im seeing is that the converters seem to not be able to comprehend the many nested data values. And the reason I think the converters are wrong is because when I try to convert back to json using them, I dont receive the same structure.

Does anyone know how to manually format this json into csv format, or know of a reliable converter than can handle nested values?

Comment: Well the CSV format implies that you are dealing with a *regular* table. There is no way of representing a treelike structure properly in a CSV file. However, if the structure you are "converting" always has the same structure and the same number of children you can translate the tree structure into columns that you use for all elements in the same way. I. e.: you will have to "flatten" your structure first before generating the CVS file.

Answer (score 0):

Try

www.json-buddy.com/convert-json-csv-xml.htm

if not working for you then you can try this tool

http://download.cnet.com/JSON-to-CSV/3000-2383_4-76680683.html

should be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your json on this for url:

http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

As a result:
UnitNumber,DataSource,ContractNumber,CarNumber,ControllerTypeMessageId,NumberOfLandings,CreatedBy,CommissionModeMessageId,Details/0/DetailName,Details/0/DetailNumber,UnitDevices/0/DeviceTypeMessageId,UnitDevices/0/CreatedBy
TestUnit13,Factory,TestContract13,2,4,4,user1,2,TestFloor13,5,1,user1

Because it could save the path of the key,like the 'DeviceTypeMessageId' in  list 'UnitDevices': it will named the columns name with 'UnitDevices/0/DeviceTypeMessageId', this could avoid the same name mistake, so you can get the columns name by its converter rules.

Hope helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

If the file `filter.jq` contains

```
def denormalize:
  def headers($p):
      keys_unsorted[] as $k
    | if   .[$k]|type == "array" then (.[$k]|first|headers("\($p)\($k)_"))
      else "\($p)\($k)"
      end
  ;
  def setup:
    [
      keys_unsorted[] as $k
    | if   .[$k]|type == "array" then [ .[$k][]| setup ]
      else .[$k]
      end
    ]
  ;
  def iter:
    if length == 0 then []
    elif .[0]|type != "array" then
      [.[0]] + (.[1:] | iter)
    else
        (.[0][] | iter) as $x
      | (.[1:]  | iter) as $y
      | [$x[]] + $y
    end
  ;
  [ headers("") ], (setup | iter)
;

denormalize | @csv
```

and `data.json` contains (note extra samples added)

```
{
  "GroupName": "GrpName13",
  "Notes": "Test Group ",
  "Number": 3,
  "Units": [
    {
      "CarNumber": "2",
      "CommissionModeMessageId": 2,
      "ContractNumber": "TestContract13",
      "ControllerTypeMessageId": 4,
      "CreatedBy": "user1",
      "DataSource": "Factory",
      "Details": [
        {
          "DetailName": "TestFloor13",
          "DetailNumber": "5"
        }
      ],
      "NumberOfLandings": 4,
      "UnitDevices": [
        {
          "CreatedBy": "user1",
          "DeviceTypeMessageId": 1
        },
        {
          "CreatedBy": "user10",
          "DeviceTypeMessageId": 10
        }
      ],
      "UnitNumber": "TestUnit13"
    },
    {
      "CarNumber": "99",
      "CommissionModeMessageId": 99,
      "ContractNumber": "Contract99",
      "ControllerTypeMessageId": 99,
      "CreatedBy": "user99",
      "DataSource": "Another Factory",
      "Details": [
        {
          "DetailName": "TestFloor99",
          "DetailNumber": "99"
        }
      ],
      "NumberOfLandings": 99,
      "UnitDevices": [
        {
          "CreatedBy": "user99",
          "DeviceTypeMessageId": 99
        }
      ],
      "UnitNumber": "Unit99"
    }
  ]
}
```

then the command

```
jq -M -r -f filter.jq data.json
```

will produce

```
"GroupName","Notes","Number","Units_CarNumber","Units_CommissionModeMessageId","Units_ContractNumber","Units_ControllerTypeMessageId","Units_CreatedBy","Units_DataSource","Units_Details_DetailName","Units_Details_DetailNumber","Units_NumberOfLandings","Units_UnitDevices_CreatedBy","Units_UnitDevices_DeviceTypeMessageId","Units_UnitNumber"
"GrpName13","Test Group ",3,"2",2,"TestContract13",4,"user1","Factory","TestFloor13","5",4,"user1",1,"TestUnit13"
"GrpName13","Test Group ",3,"2",2,"TestContract13",4,"user1","Factory","TestFloor13","5",4,"user10",10,"TestUnit13"
"GrpName13","Test Group ",3,"99",99,"Contract99",99,"user99","Another Factory","TestFloor99","99",99,"user99",99,"Unit99"
```